# python flask deactive checkbox and get id

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to set two categories with a selection box

```
<select name="categories" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="0">Categori 0</option>
    <option value="1">Categori 1</option>
</select>
```

then there will be checkboxes in two different categories

```
<input class="form-check-input" name="N1" type="checkbox" id="a1" value="A" disabled>
<input class="form-check-input" name="N1" type="checkbox" id="a2" value="B" disabled>
<input class="form-check-input" name="N1" type="checkbox" id="a3" value="C" disabled>

<input class="form-check-input" name="N2" type="checkbox" id="a4" value="X" disabled>
<input class="form-check-input" name="N2" type="checkbox" id="a5" value="Y" disabled>
<input class="form-check-input" name="N2" type="checkbox" id="a6" value="Z" disabled>
```

and a script code. If I select category 1 name="N1", if I select category 2 name="N2" checkbox will be active.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $('select[name="categories"]').change(function(){
           $('input[name="N1"]').prop('disabled',this.value != 1 ?false:true);
         });
         $('select[name="categories"]').change(function(){
           $('input[name="N2"]').prop('disabled',this.value != 0 ?false:true);
         });
        });
```

So far, everything is complete. However, I cannot call id with value from routes.

```
@bp.route('/activity_type_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def activity_type_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data1 = request.form.get('a1')
        data2 = request.form.get('a2')
        ..........
        ..........
    return render_template('activity_type_form.html', title=_('Company Profile'))
```

maybe I can proceed by typing name="N1", name="N2", name="N3", so I could get the name value I want from routes. But I couldn't find a way to bulk give the name values to the script code.

```
$('input[name="N1", name="N2", name="N3"]').prop('disabled',this.value != 1 ?false:true);
```

My goal is to just tick the checkbox in the selected category. Maybe making others invisible is damned.
Or, by running the script code over "id" values, to make only the selected category active / deactive. Your comments and suggestions will be welcomed.
Thanks for your valuable ideas in advance..

Answer (score 0):

i find a way.. not perfect but..

```
$('input[name="N1"], input[name="N2"], input[name="N3"]').prop('disabled',this.value != 1 ?false:true);
```

It has been a long way but I can both command javascript and get name values from routes.